# How can i authenticate to a website with Alladin Token certificate

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am trying to authenticate to a website using HtmlUnit but the website request certificate PKCS11 from Alladin token on USB.

I get the certificate from token but i don`t know how to use it.
Do i have to create sslContext and assign to WebClientOptions ?

Any indications ?